Probability of rank of a specific random matrix
Given matrix of size M x 6M, filled randomly with -1 or +1. The sum of elements in any row is equal to 0 (equal amount of -1 and +1).
I want to find a probability, that matrix rank will be equal to M.

The way I read your question, the problem is: "Let $X={A\in{-1,1}^{M\times 6M},:, \forall i, \sum_j A_{ij}=0}$ and let $\Bbb P:\mathcal P(X)\to [0,\infty)$, $\Bbb P(U)=\frac{\lvert U\rvert}{\lvert X\rvert}$. Find $\Bbb P{A\in X,:, \operatorname{rk}A=M}$." Is this correct?

Yes, but I didn't get the part with "U"

$\Bbb P$ is the probability, therefore it takes sets and returns numbers in $[0,1]$; $\lvert \bullet\rvert$ is the cardinality of the set.
